# Cygwin-LFTP transfer from Linux Permissions Errors

Tags: linux, cygwin, lftp

I have a Windows daily driver which I often need to transfer files to from a remote Linux file hoster. I use Cygwin and LFTP to accomplish this, and it gets the job done, with one annoying snag. On the remote server, all the files default to full access for owner and group, but no permissions for other. When transferred to the Windows machine, all the files must be fiddled with to fix the permissions so I can actually use them (namely .exe's not giving me permission.)

I transfer the files with `mirror --use-pget` and have tried the options `-p`, `-a`, and `--no-umask`. None of these change the output at all.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the error lied in Cygwin itself. Taking full control of the cygwin install directory (Or at least the directory where you are transferring files to) and all sub-folders & files makes the newly transferred files fully usable.